# What is Block in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have been trying to learn about `Block` in Yii2 from [Yii2 guide](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-views.md#using-blocks-). In the block section, I have found some code like:

```
<?php $this->beginBlock('block1'); ?>

...content of block1...

<?php $this->endBlock(); ?>
```

I am trying to implement this code and put it into a `view` file but not getting result or output because I am new with this things and do not understand how to use it. Can you tell me someone what is `Block`, how to use it and why we should use it.

Comment: Is the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-block.html) unclear? What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Actually, I do not know the use of this `terms`

Answer (score 8):

The block class extends the Yii widget class for one single purpose. To allow returning of a 'block of code' as a string instead of displaying inline.

This can be useful for example if you want to re-use several times, a piece of html which is generated at run-time.

**Implementation**

To declare a part of code in a view as a block, first surround it by begin and end statements as suggested in the question with an appropriate name

```
<?php $this->beginBlock('myblock') ?>
...<div>your html & php mixed code here</div>....
<?php $this->endBlock() ?>
```

( you may addditionally pass a 2nd parameter as true to begin block if you need to display it in the original location as well)

Next you can use that named block anywhere in the same view or a child view as many times as you like

```
echo $this->blocks['myblock']
```

Comment: can this be used to create a block in a different file?, i would like to know if there is a way to create a block from a different file and then call it from other views when i need it

Comment: You may use partial views. Another good idea may be to actually make widgets and make blocks part of these with each block in a separate file included in widget based on the call.